# Why it is necessary to consider positive $ \ x,y \ $ in $ F\ $?

Tags: ordered-fields

If $ F $ is an ordered field , then for any positive elements $x $ and $y$ in $F$ there is a natural number $ n$ such that $ nx>y \ $ i.e.,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{x+ \cdots+ x}_{n \ \text{times}}>y .
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the Archimedian property.

But my question is -

Why it is necessary to consider positive $ \ x,y \ $ in $ F\ $?

Because since $ F $ is ordered field , there can be other orders except positivity.

So I think $x,y$ to be positive is not necessary.

Help me to clear my confusion.

Comment: If $x\le 0$ and $y>0$, there is *no* natural number $n$ such that $nx>y$. Not a problem as the definition of the field being Archimedean is concerned.

Comment: Is my definition correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the definition by stating the property as

> for all $x,y\in F$, if $x\ne0$ then there exists an *integer* $n$ such that $nx>|y|$.

The meaning of $|y|$ is the usual one: $|y|=y$ if $y\ge0$ and $|y|=-y$ if $y<0$.

Exercise: prove that this is equivalent to the standard statement of the property.

Comment: $n|x|>|y|$ would be more symmetrical.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This would make the usage of *integers* useless. `;-)`

Comment: Integers are not so welcome here as the theorem is based on the "$n$ times" idea.

Comment: that means my definition is correct

Comment: @yourmath What definition? With no restriction on $x$ and with $n$ a natural number? Not at all.

Comment: @egreg, $ x $ is restricted to be postive and $ n $ is natural number I mentioned above. Why not you are saying that my definition wrong or right?

Comment: @egreg, I mean this one- If $ F $ is an ordered field , then for any positive numbers $x $ and $y$ in $F$ there is a natural number $ n$ such that $ nx>y \ $ i.e.,   
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{x+ \cdots+ x}_{n \ \text{times}}>y .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @yourmath $x$ and $y$ are *not* numbers, but elements of $F$. This is the *standard* Archimedean property. Here “positive” refers to the *given* ordering in $F$.

Comment: @egreg, so the definition is- If $ F $ is an ordered field , then for any positive elements  $x $ and $y$ in $F$ there is a natural number $ n$ such that $ nx>y \ $ i.e.,   
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{x+ \cdots+ x}_{n \ \text{times}}>y .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: @yourmath Yes, but then what's your question?

Comment: @egreg, this was the question. I asked whether it is right or not which I wrote . I just asked to correct my definition

Comment: @yourmath If you are worried about the definition you quote about the [Archimedian property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) then just have a look at Wikipedia. If it concerns your own thinking then the answers are enough.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because $n$ is positive.

Comment: So my definition is correct

Comment: @yourmath: which definition ?

Comment: which I mentioned above in my questiion

Comment: @yourmath: I see no definition in your post.

Comment: I mean this one- If $ F $ is an ordered field , then for any positive numbers $x $ and $y$ in $F$ there is a natural number $ n$ such that $ nx>y \ $ i.e.,   
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{x+ \cdots+ x}_{n \ \text{times}}>y .
\end{eqnarray*} $

Comment: @yourmath: this is a proposition and it has been true since the beginning. So what ?

Comment: That is what I was asking confirmation. But all time you said : what definition? so sorry